# Tagfield with html encoded displayField in Extjs 6

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs6

Before upgrading to Extjs 6 we were using a `tagfield` component where its `displayField` was `Ext.String.htmlEncode('description')` where `description` was the description field of the store's record. This field doesn't only contain simple text but instead is in the form of: `<img src="link..." style="..."/>&nbspRECORD_DESCRIPTION`. Using the `htmlEncode` function it would actually render the tagfield's records with the linked image and the record's description.

However after upgrading to version 6 this stopped working. It now just produces the full text instead of rendering the image. Its like `htmlEncode` stopped working all of a sudden. The thing is that in an `ItemSelector` field where we do the same thing everything works perfectly using the exact same method. Did they break the `tagfield` component so as to not be able to show html?

Regardless, how can I reproduce what I did before? I tried with `displayTpl` config but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Ext.String.htmlEncode('description')` try just `'description'` in displayField. DisplayField affects what you see when you are selecting, and for that, it will display your HTML. It also affects how it displays the selections you have made, and there doesn't seem to be a way to display HTML there. It displays as plain text. There is another attribute, labelTpl, that formats the items you have already selected. You can use that to display just the names of things you have already selected. (LabelTpl used to display formatted HTML, but doesn't in ExtJs6.) Suppose your store record also had a 'name' field that is just plain text; you would put that inside curly braces:

```
xtype:'tagfield',
displayField: 'description',
labelTpl: '{name}',
...
```

Then you will get formatted HTML while making a selection, and plain text in the selected items. That's the best I've come up with so far.

Answer (score 0):

Using ExtJS 6.5.3

This is the best I was able to figure out for a tag field in terms of creating a complex display statement for both list and tags.

The display supports CSS and other HTML tags
The labelTpl does not support anything but plain text, but you can override it's **x-tagfield-item-text** style however, it's all or nothing.

```
{
            cls: "triggerstagfield",
            displayField: '[(values.key != "all") ? values.label + " (<b>" + values.key + "</b>)" : values.label]',
            labelTpl: '{[(values.key != "all") ? values.label + " (" + values.key + ")" : values.label]}',
            valueField: "key",
            store: [{
                "key": "all",
                "label": "All"
            }, {
                "key": "880",
                "label": "International House of Pancakes" 
            }]                      
        },
```

and this is the CSS

```
.triggerstagfield .x-tagfield-item-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 0.9em;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked around it by extending the built in tag field, overriding the function getMultiSelectItemMarkup. In that function I removed the call to Ext.String.htmlEncode on the label.

With this you can use

```
{ 
  xtype: 'tagfieldhtmllabel',
  labelTpl: '<span style="background-color:#{colorbg};">{name}</span>',
  ...
}
```

This is the code that works on Ext 6.2.1

```
Ext.define("Private.ui.TagFieldHtmlLabel", {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Tag',
    alias: 'widget.tagfieldhtmllabel',

    // TODO EXT UPGRADE. WHEN UPGRADING FROM 6.2.1 update this
    getMultiSelectItemMarkup: function() {
        var me = this,
            childElCls = (me._getChildElCls && me._getChildElCls()) || '';
        // hook for rtl cls
        if (!me.multiSelectItemTpl) {
            if (!me.labelTpl) {
                me.labelTpl = '{' + me.displayField + '}';
            }
            me.labelTpl = me.lookupTpl('labelTpl');
            if (me.tipTpl) {
                me.tipTpl = me.lookupTpl('tipTpl');
            }
            me.multiSelectItemTpl = new Ext.XTemplate([
                '<tpl for=".">',
                '<li data-selectionIndex="{[xindex - 1]}" data-recordId="{internalId}" role="presentation" class="' + me.tagItemCls + childElCls,
                '<tpl if="this.isSelected(values)">',
                ' ' + me.tagSelectedCls,
                '</tpl>',
                '{%',
                'values = values.data;',
                '%}',
                me.tipTpl ? '" data-qtip="{[this.getTip(values)]}">' : '">',
                '<div role="presentation" class="' + me.tagItemTextCls + '">{[this.getItemLabel(values)]}</div>',
                '<div role="presentation" class="' + me.tagItemCloseCls + childElCls + '"></div>',
                '</li>',
                '</tpl>',
                {
                    isSelected: function(rec) {
                        return me.selectionModel.isSelected(rec);
                    },
                    getItemLabel: function(values) {
                        // UPGRADE - removed htmlEncode here
                        return me.labelTpl.apply(values);
                    },
                    getTip: function(values) {
                        return Ext.String.htmlEncode(me.tipTpl.apply(values));
                    },
                    strict: true
                }
            ]);
        }
        if (!me.multiSelectItemTpl.isTemplate) {
            me.multiSelectItemTpl = this.lookupTpl('multiSelectItemTpl');
        }
        return me.multiSelectItemTpl.apply(me.valueCollection.getRange());
    }


});
```